Are all volkswagen jetta engines either Fsi or TSI?
I am gearing up to buy a Volkswagen Jetta 2.5 2010 (petrol). Based on my research, it's better to stay away from those with FSI engines.
The TSI engine also has its own issues.
Are there Jetta's with engines that are neither FSI, TSI nor TFSI? If there are, what are they called?
I just want a Jetta that will give me the least worries.
Right now, I am hunting for a mechanic that specialises in VW cars.
By the way, I live in Nigeria.
